# Sample python code for Account Linking in Amazon Alexa

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, ask-sdk

Where can i find the sample Python code for Account linking in Amazon Alexa. I was only able to get the documentation here.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/account-linking/understand-account-linking.html

Please help me !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Account linking works the same way for all languages and you should be familiar with `OAuth2` to configure account linking in developer portal.

> Users can link account in two ways:
>
> 1. From the skill detail card in the Alexa app while enabling the skill.
> 2. From a link account card in the Alexa app after making a request that requires authentication.

When you link an account with your skill, every subsequent request from the skill will include an access token. You can then use this `accessToken` to get associated data for linked account.

```
"session": {
        "new": true,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.xxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.xxxxxxx",
            "accessToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

For an authenticated usecase, always check whether the `accessToken` is available and  when there is no `accessToken` in the request that means that the user is not authenticated and you can send the user an `Account Link Card`. Except for the code to send an `Account Link card` there is no coding involved in **link-an-account** process.

**To send Account Link Card**:

In your response JSON include `LinkAccount` card

```
...
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak> Please link your account </speak>"
            },
            "card": {
                "type": "LinkAccount"
            }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

To send the Account Link card in Python…

```
from ask_sdk_model.ui import Card

…

handler_input.response_builder.set_card(Card('LinkAccount'))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the function `get_account_linking_access_token()` from ASK SDK for python, to get the user token for account linking
and store in the variable `account_linking_token`.  Use the token to fetch the user data if account linking has been done, as shown below:

```
from ask_sdk_model.ui import SimpleCard

speech_output = ''

if account_linking_token is not None:
   url = "https://api.amazon.com/user/profile?access_token{}"\
         .format(account_linking_token)
   user_data = requests.get(url).json()
   # retrieve the required user info here and populate output
   # speech_output = ...
else:
   # output msg when account linking is not done
   # speech_output = ...

# return this response from the intent handler function
response = handler_input.response_builder
            .speak(speech_output)
            .ask(reprompt)
            .set_card(SimpleCard(speech_output))
            .response
```