# ask-sdk python to return LinkAccountCard

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, ask-sdk

I'm newbie to Alexa custom skill and if my users trigger an intent which requires authentication, i want them to link their accounts to continue using my skill. Of course my skill needs to return an instructions for them to know how to link their account.

I found in the [Officical docs](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/add-account-linking-logic-custom-skill.html#respond-if-missing) but unfortunately there is no example code for python.
After hours researching on internet, i found [LinkAccountClass](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-apis-for-python/blob/master/ask-sdk-model/ask_sdk_model/ui/link_account_card.py) on `ask_sdk_model.ui`. So i started to add this class to my code like that:

`from ask_sdk_model.ui import LinkAccountCard
    if not handler_input.request_envelope.context.system.user.access_token:
         speech =  "You must open alexa app on your phone and link you account to continue"
         handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech).set_card(LinkAccountCard(speech))
    return handler_input.response_builder.set_should_end_session(False).response`

But Alexa keeps saying to me that "Sorry, i can't help you with this". If i use `.set_card(SimpleCard(speech))` instead of `.set_card(LinkAccountCard(speech))`, Alexa display the message "You must open alexa app on your phone and link you account to continue" without any error.
So how can i return the linkAccountCard to user to help them go to the linking accout in setting?

Thank a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sample python code for Account Linking in Amazon Alexa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358106/sample-python-code-for-account-linking-in-amazon-alexa)

Comment: No, i found that answer. I tried to follow that instruction but nothing happened, because there was no code in that post. So that i decided to post the new question here :(

Comment: We use `from ask_sdk_model.iu import Card` and `Card('LinkAccount')` but this produces the same (working) end result as what have. I also tested it ending and not ending the session. I think you've got a problem elsewhere... but I can't find it in the code you've provided. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: the problem was i passed speech as parameter to LinkAccountCard(), so it didnt work.
I changed to "from ask_sdk_model.iu import Card" to import and "handler_input.response_builder.set_card(Card('LinkAccount'))" in the response and then it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkAccountCard` doesn't accept any parameters; change it to `.set_card(LinkAccountCard())` and you should be good. Alexa provides the copy for that card.

Alternatively, you could use…

```
from ask_sdk_model.ui import Card

… 

handler_input.response_builder.set_card(Card('LinkAccount'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass any parameters to the `LinkAccountCard`

Here's a sample code:

```py
from ask_sdk_model.ui import LinkAccountCard

...

return handler_input.response_builder.speak("Hello").set_card(LinkAccountCard()).response
```